# Border is cutting off

Tags: html, css

As you can see on the screenshot below, in my sidebar the right border of "KULTUR" is cutting off. Its always at the last element of the row.

[image]

I have tried to change margins and paddings but it's not working unfortunately.

Here is the URL to my website: http://holmsbuopplevelser.dahlsdata-test.com

It's in the right sidebar if you scroll down a bit.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Use `display: inline-block` instead of `inline`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
.widget_categories li{
   display: inline-block; //rather display:inline
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I had checked your code and it is the only way you can manage tags with dynamic width and fix it!
find class ".widget_categories li" in your css and change display from "inline" to "inline-block".

```
.widget_categories li{
      display: inline-block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

some of your li and buttons have this problem , add `display:block` to the buttons , and add `display:inline-block` to li , this will fix your issue, i checked your site

```
span.vc_gitem-post-category-name {
   display:block;
}

.widget_categories li{
   display: inline-block; 
}
```